# Wordpress: uploading images with special characters gets the characters replaced

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, wordpress-theming, special-characters

So, I have 2 sites. One in production, and the another in development. They have the same content and uploads.

In production, images with names containing `æ`, `ø`, or `å` gets the character replaced with something else, for example `ø` get replaced with `Ã`¸, and then saved in the upload folder. And it works! Wordpress somehow gets the right image when I request it.

E.g: `wp-content/upload/2015/01/interiørtips.jpg` will display the image `interiÃ¸rtips.jpg`.

In the database, the references to the images are saved normally, including the special characters; `æøå` is used in the name, not some other obscure character combination. This means that the database is ok.

I exported all the content from production to a fresh database in development, but now every image which has either an `æ`, `ø`, or `å` in it wont load the same way as in production. The request `wp-content/upload/2015/01/interiørtips.jpg` won't load anything, but `wp-content/upload/2015/01/interiÃ¸rtips.jpg` will. This is opposite of the behavior in production.

Does anyone know anything about this?

EDIT: I'll probably just some rename tool. But, if anyone has any insights, please share.